# Selected value in the dropdownlistfor doesnt retrieve the value id

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I have 2 class models, one is called WorkCategory and the second one is called ServiceCategory. Based on each category selected from the dropdown(WorkCategory) it will populate the second dropdown with data from the second class(ServiceCategory) based on the foreign key.

The first dropdown is populated from the database without javascript, in the second dropdown I populate the value with javascript based on the first dropdown with the method on change.

This is my model view which has the attributes that I want to capture.

```
 public class PostJobViewModel
{

    [Required]
    public WorkCategory Category { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string JobAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AboutJob { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string JobCity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string JobPostCode { get; set; }

    public ServiceCategory JobService { get; set; }
}
```

This is the first dropdown which populates well from DB and also when I post the form has the ID of the selected option.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category.CategoryName, ViewBag.whatWorkToBeDone as SelectList, "-- Select Category --", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange="FillService()" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Category.CategoryName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

and this is the second dropdown list which is populated on runtime with Ajax, based on the first selected option.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobService.Category, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "ServiceId", "ServiceName"), "-- Select Service --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.JobService.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

The problem that I have is when I debug the controller the "JobService" is always null even though the option has a value of ids. Despite this, the modelstate is not valid and it throws an error on the UI saying "The value '14' is invalid.(where 14 is the number(id) but for some reason is presented like string).

And here below is the JavaScript/ajax call which I populate the dropdown.

```
     function FillService() {
    var serviceId = $('#Category_CategoryName').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FillServ", "PostJob")',
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "JSON",
        data: { ServiceCategory: serviceId },
        success: function (services) {
            if (services == '') {

               // $('#step-wizard').load(' .step-anchor');

                document.getElementById('JobService_Category').disabled = true;
                $("#Title-Category").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $("#JobService_Category").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $("#Title-Category").append('Please skip this step!');

                $("#secondStep").html("");
                $("#secondStep").append('Skip this step!');
            } else {

                document.getElementById('JobService_Category').disabled = false;
                $("#JobService_Category").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $.each(services, function (i, service) {
                    $("#JobService_Category").append($('<option></option>').val(service.ServiceId).html(service.ServiceName));
                });


            }

        }
    });
```

what is wrong with this?

---UPDATE---

ServiceCategory Class

```
 public class ServiceCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    public WhatToHaveDone Category { get; set; }

    public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
}




public class WhatToHaveDone
{
    [Key]
    public int WhatToDoneId { get; set; }
    public string WhatToDoneItem { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ServiceCategory> Services { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the Method that returns data from the Api call in ajax

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult FillServ(int ServiceCategory)
    {
        var services = (from s in _context.JobService where s.Category.WhatToDoneId == ServiceCategory select s).ToList();
        return Json(services, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

controller debug

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PostJobViewModel JobModel, List<HttpPostedFileBase> jobImages)
    {

        if (User.Identity.Name == "")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
        }
        else
        {
        var imgList = new List<JobImage>();

            var user = (from u in _context.Users where u.Email == User.Identity.Name select u.Id).First();
            foreach (var item in jobImages)
        {
                var newJobimage = new JobImage
                {
                    JobFileName = item.FileName,
                    JobImageContentBytes = new byte[item.ContentLength],


                };
                imgList.Add(newJobimage);
            }


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            var newJob = new JobPost{
                Category = JobModel.Category,
                JobAddress=JobModel.JobAddress,
                AboutJob=JobModel.AboutJob,
                JobCity=JobModel.JobCity,
                JobPostCode=JobModel.JobPostCode,

                JobImages=imgList,
                UserId = user,
                JobService=JobModel.JobService

            };
            _context.jobPosts.Add(newJob);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {

        }
        }

        var workCategories = new SelectList(_context.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
        ViewBag.WorkCategories = workCategories;

        var whatWorkToBeDone = new SelectList(_context.JobWizardCategories, "WhatToDoneId", "WhatToDoneItem");
        ViewBag.whatWorkToBeDone = whatWorkToBeDone;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the `ServiceCategory` class as well please. Specifically what is the data type of `ServiceCategory.Category`?

Comment: Also... "when I debug the controller the "JobService" is always null". Specifically which controller method are you debugging, and when? You didn't show us any of that code, despite that being where you've noticed symptoms of a problem.

Comment: @ADyson The ServiceCategory.Category is type WhatToHaveDone class. basically I want to retrieve from category the services related to it, does it make sense now? Please see updated section in the post.

Comment: Right, so in that case `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobService.Category` really makes no sense, because you can only really bind a dropdownlist field to a simple type like integer or string, not an object. Maybe `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobService.ServiceId` would make more sense? Or `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobService.Category.WhatToDoneId` ? I don't actually know which ID you're trying to map it to.

Comment: @ADyson Please see the method which is being hit after I post the form.

Comment: That's useful information but it doesn't directly answer my question. Which ID field are you trying to bind the mentioned dropdown list to? You can't bind it to a whole object.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for you time it was really useful. so what I did I changed instead of .Category to .ServiceId and then I changed in the Ajax call the Id of the dropdown.

Comment: Ok good. So, does it work as you wanted now?

Comment: Yes, it is working as expected now. Thanks for your help! :)